# How to debug jQuery in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, console

I'm looking at the jQuery progress bar example from here: 
https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Here is the code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
     value: 76
    });
   });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>jQuery progress bar</h2>
  <div id="progressbar" class="bar"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I put `console.log` somewhere to see the value of variable `value` which equals to 76? I've tried `console.log(value)`, `console.log($("#progressbar").value)`, `console.log($("#progressbar").progressbar.value)`, none of these works.

Comment: From the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#method-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `progress bar` is taking an object as `param` so you can do your `console.log` that way: `the option` and the `option name`

For **Example**  to get the value : `progressbar("option", "value")`

**OR**

`progressbar("value")`

I recommend reading the documentation for more details:

[Progress bar](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 76
  });

  //Get the progress bar value

  const value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");

  console.log(value)
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>jQuery progress bar</h2>
  <div id="progressbar" class="bar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are just logging the object you created. Not the actual value of the progress bar